# Using two ManagedObjectContexts when editing a previously saved entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using two contexts so that if the user creates my NSManagedObjectModel subclass, AddressAnnotation (points on a map), when the user creates a new route (my other entity that has a to-many relationship to AddressAnnotation), then if they decide to cancel, I can easily throw away the objects because they were created in a tempContext.  So that code looks like this:

```
        AddressAnnotation *anAddress = [AddressAnnotation insertAddressAnnotationWithCoordinate:coordinate inManagedObjectContext:self.tempContext];
        [self.route addAddressAnnotationsObject:anAddress];
```

Then when I save the address and route, I do this:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [self.route managedObjectContext];

    [tempContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![tempContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"an error occurred: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"error in main context: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    }];
```

So that part works fine.  The problem I have now is, in another view controller where I show these saved routes, the routes are coming from the self.managedObjectContext, my main context.  So after I show the saved routes, if they select it, then it goes back to the map so they can add more to it.  I do that on my storyboard with this:

```
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
        [destination setValue:_managedObjectContext forKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
    }
```

But now, when I try to call the `[self.route addAddressAnnotationsObject:anAddress];` because the self.tempContext is different than the route's context, I can't add it.  I also can't just say that the main context is now the tempcontext.  Any thoughts on how I should go about this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`self.route` is in `self.managedObjectContext`, but `anAddress` is in `self.tempContext`. To fix that you have to get `objectID` of `self.route` and then use it to find that object in `self.tempContext` with:

```
- (NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: That does not work in my case since tempContext doesn't exist in my SavedRoutesViewController.  Maybe that is the problem I am having.  But basically, tempContext only exists when I want to create a new object so that if the user never decides to save anything, then the tempContext will just go away.  It's only when they save, does the object exist in the self.managedObjectContext.  So when I come from the SavedRoutesViewController, my saved route can only come from the self.managedObjectContext, not tempContext.  So maybe there is a better way to set this up?

Comment: To be consistent all the objects you use in the View Controller that shows map should be in `tempContext`. I don't know how your code looks but your flow in this View Controller could look like this: create `tempContext` and then either 1) create new managed object (route) in it, or 2) find in `tempContext` the route user selected in the tableView (as I've shown in my answer).